# Do we use script tags in JavaScript because it lacks a linker?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand the linking process in JavaScript in a browser environment. Feedback from the comments brought out more doubts.

Firstly, when they say JavaScript lacks a linker, who is doing the linking then?

When we use the `script` tags, are we doing the linking explicitly or is the linking done at another time or skipped entirely?

As far as I understand, linking is a process of including compiled code or object files returned by a compiler into a single file. So using `script` tags *is* linking or is it mere referencing to external `.js` files?

I do not have a thorough understanding of the linking/loading process that happens behind the scenes in a Javascript environment.

I have read Crockford's blog posts and searched a few blogs but I couldn't find a definitive answer so as to why we need to use `script` tags. Any details including language specifications would help.

Comment: `<script>` tag *is* the linker. After all, you can combine it into a single file with `<script> alert('Hello'); </script>`...

Comment: But even with compiled code, you still need to tell your program to include a reference to it, like a script tag, so I'm a bit confused on what you're actually asking

Comment: well Javascript is not compiled, for one thing. The script tag is required because the code is included as part of a HTML document, so it needs to know which parts of the document are HTML, which are script, which are other types of content

Comment: So are the `script` tags kind of manual linking?

Comment: @ADyson: Oh, JavaScript is compiled, in the majority case\*. It's just not *pre*-compiled by the programmer. (\* Just recently, V8 stopped compiling **everything** in favor of using interpretation for code that's run only once, as a [performance and memory optimization](https://v8project.blogspot.co.uk/2017/05/launching-ignition-and-turbofan.html).)

Answer (score 2):

No, it's an implication of JavaScript and HTML being two separate languages. Even so, the script element allows embedding of scripts into HTML files without linking to external .js files.

For external .js files, the script element *is* the linker, if you will (and even that is a stretch, considering that neither JavaScript nor HTML is "compiled" in the traditional sense of the word, but depending on whom you ask, code is code however you spin it).

Comment: So when we use the `script` tags, we are kind of manually linking our js code (which isn't compiled though)? Am I right in thinking this?

Comment: @aliasav: You can think of it that way, yeah. In all honesty HTML has a slightly different definition of "linking" to resources compared to the traditional definition, but just as code is code, linking is linking, I guess.